# Why my AIDE not downloading Google Firebase libraries?

Tags: android, firebase, build.gradle, aide

I am using android AIDE app to make android application. Before i factory reset my android, I have all google, android & firebase libraries are downloaded & installed. But after factory reset, when i install again AIDE app, It download only google & firebase library. And when i put firebase dependency in build gradle, it not downloading firebase library for me. Please help me in these case.

Here's my build gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.rb.aagrikoli"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:+'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:+'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.3.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the latest versions of all library in your gradle file
try to replace all the library accourding to your target SDK
Also change the `compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"` to 25(same with target sdk)

Comment: I have updated my copileSdkVersion 21 and buildToolsVersion "21.1.0" to "25.0.0" and also updated libraries to latest version, but now i'am getting error to all google, android & firebase libraries. look below i'am getting error:    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.0.0'
 compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4"
 compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

Comment: replace **comile** with **Implementation** and all libarary to 25 because you are targeting sdk 25 and you are  using library 28.0.0...